# How can I troubleshoot semi-random black screen caused by graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I understand the title might be a bit confusing, so please allow me to explain…

#### The Issue

What happens is that while using the computer, every now and then I get a completely black screen. There doesn't seem to be any pattern — it may happen when browsing the internet, when typing, when playing a resource-hungry video game, or even on idle. One thing I noticed *might* have made it more frequent was the "Use Hardware Acceleration" setting of the browser; occurrences were lessened after I took that off. I've also disabled overdrive on my GPU.

The sound continues to be audible (e.g. if I'm watching YouTube, I can still hear the sound) but the screen is completely black. The only solution then is a hard reset — I've tried to create a key shortcut for rebooting the computer, which didn't work (this led me to believe the keyboard might be stuck too, I'm not sure).

In the greater scheme of things, this occurs *very* rarely — whole weeks can pass by without any issues, even when the graphics card works hard (i.e. playing games). But I noticed that, when it happens, it might very soon happen again. In other words, whole weeks might go by without a freeze, and then I have 1-2 daily for a few days.

#### The "Semi-Random" Part

Recently, however, I *think* I discovered a pattern. As a matter of habit, I perform a disk check after hard reset — a remnant from older times; I don't know if there's a point with SSDs… — followed by removing temp files etc. using BleachBit.

I don't know what kind of inspiration I got, but I thought to skip this latter procedure (removing temp and other files). It seems to have worked, in the sense that in the past few weeks I only had one single such case, which wasn't followed by another soon after.

#### My Question

I understand all this might be entirely random, but

- is it possible that there is a some connection between the
  graphics card acting up and some temp (or similar) file?
- how do I troubleshoot such a thing? What kinds of files should I avoid
  deleting to see if it's connected?

#### Additional Details

To me, it's fairly obvious this is a graphics card issue, as I've had this intermittently over the years with every computer that had a graphics cars (i.e. GPU separate from the motherboard). I **never** faced this issue with computers lacking a graphics card (e.g. laptops).

This specific computer runs Windows 7 with all the latest updates (including drivers). The card is an AMD Radeon R7 200

Comment: My computers also have/had GPUs and I never encountered such problems. It might rather be connected to some product that you always install on your computers.

Comment: Have you reached out to AMD's tech support?  That's probably the most efficient way to figure out what's causing this.  Also, `chkdsk` should still be run on SSDs, as it's not about the storage type but the fact the drive had a dirty unmount _(normal defrag should never be ran on an SSD though, as they require TRIM)_ and laptops do come with discrete graphics =]